# Help me to solve this riddle

Tags: riddle

I am a person.
People say that I look like a cat, but I am not, cats walk on all four, and I walk on two.
I am a person.
I also hold the sun, and they call me the Messiah, or the Savior.
My favorite food is pancakes that my mama makes.

**Who am I?**

Comment: The anwser is 4 letters Xxxx

Comment: Hi @asd, welcome to PSE! Based on the title, it seems like this is not a puzzle you created.  If this is the case, please provide the source.  Similarly, the comment you made should be in the question, not as a comment.  (You may even want to hide it with the spolier tag ">!")

Comment: I think I know it. How can I post the answer without spoiling?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli post your answer in "anwer" and not "comment" and write >! before the spoil ;)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> I think it is Bast.
>  Firstly, Bast has a cat's head, but she walks on two legs, so it fits the second line.
>  Secondly, she is the counterpart of Sekhmet, which was the other aspect of the goddess (basically the same goddess), so in the riddle she says 'me'. Sekhmet represents the powerful warrior aspect of the goddess, which is why they call her the Saviour, so it fits the fourth line.
>  Bast was also said to be the daughter of Ra, so she 'holds the sun' by holding Ra's bloodline?
>  And offerings to Bast include sweet foodstuff, so she might like pancakes?

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's

> Bast or Bastet from Ancient Egypt as she is goddess of protection and cats.
>  She was worshiped at least since the Second Dynasty in Ancient Egypt. The center of her cult was in Per-Bast (Bubastis in Greek), which was named after her.
>
>  [image]

Comment: I'm not sure this fits. Just because a deity is worshiped does not mean that their believers " call [them] the Messiah, or the Savior". And where do the pancakes come in?

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Niko?

Because

> his favorite food is Pancakes, he has cat eyes, and it just makes sense and one of his powers is like throwing a sun ball or something.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Where is Niko from? I don't know what he is

Comment: @YoutRied The game OneShot